# Need to change the Product Image size on category page woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have a woocommerce website, on the category page its show list of product, but the product image on the category page is thumbnail. i want to show full image of products in category page, please help me from where in the code i changed that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't require coding (assuming your theme hasn't changed Woocommerce's default behaviour.)

You can change the image sizes in the Woocommerce settings -> Products->Product images, in admin.

For the categories pages, you want the `'Catalogue Images'`.

You then need to regenerate thumbnails to apply the change to all existing images. You can use this plugin for that - https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

If you do want/need to go down the coding route, then you need to override the relevant Woocommerce template file, in your own theme. Or, maybe just override an `action` (remove Woocommerce's one and add your own).

I can't tell you exaclty what you need to do, based on the info in your question, but you need to either copy a template file into your theme, or add your own function to hook into the relevant template.

And then, it will be a matter of changing the `image size` string in the function that produces the image. For the full image, you want this image size:

```
'full'
```

(there is no 'shop_full', so you just use the native `full` size that WordPress provides)

Answer (score -1):

Use below code:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10 );

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title',
function() {
    echo woocommerce_get_product_thumbnail( 'product-category', 294, 294 );},10);
```